# Get the next set of points in the foreach loop so I can find polygon's length

Tags: c#

I'm using list to store a number of polygons, and point class to store the points of the polygons. I can get each point individually I need to calculate the length of the polygon..So I need the next points too. How to get them

```
 foreach (Point point in and[reqi])
 {             
     int x1 = point.X;
     int y1 = point.Y;

     MessageBox.Show(x1.ToString());
     MessageBox.Show(y1.ToString());
 }
```

How do I get the next points in the Class point in this part t o calculate length of the polygon?

Comment: How did you define your list? As a List<Point> as you should? BTW, you can write  MessageBox.Show("Point " + point ); - What is `and` and what is `requ`? - If you mean you want to calculate the sum of the sides of a polygon you should write a function `float distance(Point A, Point B)` using pythargoras in it.. - Also: while `foreach` is nice is it not a good choice for this case; stick to the old-fashioned `for` loop!

Comment: List<List<Point>> and = new List<List<Point>>();
This is how i have my list...I have a set of polygons in which i have points of each polygon.."reqi" is used to select the polygon required..

Comment: Sounds fine so far. (Well, almost: `and` is not a good name, imo..) Now get rid of the foreach loop! use `for (int i=0; i < and[reqi].Count - 1; i++){ sum += distance(and[reqi][i], and[reqi][i+1]);`

Comment: I usualy rename at last...I can get the current points ..but to calculate length i need the next points too..i have no idea how to get them..I can assign each point to a variable and calculate but it would be so long and there has to be some other way..

Comment: is it possible to use list as a double array ? :O ill let u kno after trying...

Comment: You can access any list by an indexer, which looks just like an array. Actually behind the scenes Lists are arrays anyway, but that is beside the point. Yes, the two indexers will work as if you had a  array of array.

Comment: Tnks im new to c# .. i get += is invalid expression terms ..any ways to use it..i also wanted to use it b4 but tried smg else

Comment: Well, you need to define a `float sum = 0f`and the distance function.. `+=` mean 'add the right side to the left side'. Is is a shorthand for `sum = sum + someothernumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the last segment :

```
// Normal loop on each point : compute distance to previous point
float polyLength=0 ;
for (int i=0;i<PolyPoints[i].Count;i++) 
{ 
  float deltaX = (PolyPoint[i].X-PolyPoint[i-1].X) ;
  float deltaY = (PolyPoint[i].Y-PolyPoint[i-1].Y) ;
  PolyLength  += (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY) ;
}

if (PolyPoint[PolyPoint.Count-1]!=PolyPoint[0])
{ // last point different from first point : compute distance from last point to first one
  float deltaX = (PolyPoint[PolyPoint.Count-1].X-PolyPoint[0].X) ;
  float deltaY = (PolyPoint[PolyPoint.Count-1].Y-PolyPoint[0].Y) ;
  PolyLength  += (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY) ;
}
```